# How can I convert a dense time series to a sparse one in openTSDB?

Tags: opentsdb

I'm using openTSDB, and I want to use it to efficiently convert a *dense time series* to a *sparse time series*.  Here's what I mean:   The dense time series consists of samples on a strictly regular cadence, while in a sparse time series there are no constraints on the sample times.   In my case, the dense time series changes relatively infrequently, so I could save some processing time (maybe) if I would subset the samples to those whose value differs from the previous sample.

What I'm wondering is: is there something in openTSDB (v2.4), maybe something related to the `rate` option, that would allow this kind of conversion as a processing filter so that I'd only get back those relatively infrequent change points?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the underlying series doesn't have to be regular to be eligible for this type of transformation which essentially is a lossless (RLE) or lossy compression.

Comment: Yes.   Any ideas how to do it efficiently w/ openTSDB?

Comment: As far as I know, OpenTSDB doesn't provide built-in support for this transformation. The rate transformation returns the 1st derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Axibase Time Series Database is compatible with the OpenTSDB `tcollector` protocol and supports a `downsample` [transformation](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/api/data/series/downsample.html) in REST API to reduce time series density.

[image]

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.